# Using Foundation Data Abide Validations in Modal (AJAX) doesn't Validate. `

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, validation, zurb-foundation

I can't get Data Abide to validate my fields in a modal (Foundation 5, Simple Form, Ruby on Rails).

Anyone know how to validate fields in a modal with AJAX using data-abide from Foundation?

```
<%= simple_form_for [current_user, @photo, @tag], id: "tagform", :remote => true do |f| %>
    <div class="center semi_padding new_tag_form">
      <%= f.input :name , label: "Marca: ", :required => "[a-zA-Z]+" ,input_html: {class: 'marca ipt'} %>
      <%= f.input :location, label: "¿Donde lo encontraste?" , input_html: {class: 'ipt'} %>
      <%= f.input :price, label: "¿Cuanto te costó?" , input_html: {class: 'ipt'} %>
      <%= f.input :coordinate_x , as: :hidden %>
      <%= f.input :coordinate_y , as: :hidden %>
      <%= f.button :button, "Taggear", type: "button", id:"tp_tag_save", input_html: {class: 'btn-ok icon-favorite-1 button'} %>
      <%= f.button :button, "Cancelar", name: "Cancel", id: "tp_tag_cancel", input_html: {class: 'icon-cancel button'} %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: maybe it will help you: http://railscasts.com/episodes/417-foundation

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your simple_form tag:

```
html: {novalidate: "novalidate", data: {abide: ''}
```

EX:

```
<%= simple_form_for [current_user, @photo, @tag], id: "tagform", :remote => true, html: {novalidate: "novalidate", data: {abide: ''} do |f| %>
```

Then make sure to throw in a reflow call on the form when the modal is triggered by adding the following JS to the click handler:

```
$(document).foundation('abide', 'reflow');
```